# Display Wordpress categories in one column and posts in two columns using Bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display my Wordpress post categories in a  and then my posts running across two columns.

I'm new to PHP and am stuck at this point and am a bit stuck! Any help would be really helpful.

Here's a reference of what I'm trying to achieve where the categories are displayed in a smaller column and the posts run across two columns: https://nmbw.com.au/works-and-projects/

```
<div class="container">

    <?php 
    // the query
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                Categories
            </div>
        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                   </a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
    </div>
</div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the columns like this.

```
<div class="container">

<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    Categories
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- the loop -->
      <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
          </a>
        </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <!-- end of the loop -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```